# R - counting number of daily values within a specific range per factor and summarising by year

Tags: r

I have daily data and I'd like to count the number of times per year the daily measurement is within a certain range. The data is also grouped by factor, so I need to know number of days per year for each factor that is within a certain range (e.g. 15 to 18)

I have a large dataset of over 100 years but here is some data just for this example:

```
Date <- seq(as.Date("2010/01/01"), by = "day", length.out = 1095)
People <- sample.int(20, 1095, replace = TRUE)
Country <- sample(x = c("Australia", "Canada", "France"), size = 1095, replace = TRUE)

mydf <- data.frame(Date, People, Country)
```

I would like to know the number of times per year the value of "People" is between 15 and 18 for each country.

So my output would be a new dataframe, something like:

```
myDate    People    Country
2010      45        Australia
2010      10        Canada
2010      24        France
2011      33        Australia
2011      100       Canada
2011      4         France
2012      21        Australia
2012      66        Canada
2012      211       France
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm struggling with this and have looked for answers but I can't find a solution that involves the date and factor.

Comment: Always `set.seed()` with random sampling. Hence why answers below differ in output!

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve it with `lubridate` and `dplyr`. Use `year()` to grab the year and group by the year and the country. The last step is a conditional summing up:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mydf %>%
  group_by(year = year(Date), Country) %>%
  summarise(p = sum(between(People, 15, 18)))
```

---

This could yield

```
   year Country       p
  <dbl> <fct>     <int>
1 2010. Australia    22
2 2010. Canada       34
3 2010. France       26
4 2011. Australia    21
5 2011. Canada       30
6 2011. France       13
7 2012. Australia    28
8 2012. Canada       31
9 2012. France       23
```

Comment: Could also use `summarise(p = sum(between(People, 15, 18))`.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use floor_date? And I get the wrong answer (a single value rather than a by country*year set of results.

Comment: @42-: You are right, one does not need `floor_date()` here. I honestly did not understand your second issue - why are you getting a wrong answer? I get exactly the same output with your `aggregate(...)` answer.

Comment: Aha; I also loaded plyr for answering another question. The `plyr` version of `summarise` is different and gives the results I am seeing. Sorry for that noisy comment.

Answer (score 3):

And here is the requisite base solution. Key points: convert dates to character year values with `format.Date` and the by-grouping needs to be a list-object:

```
aggregate( mydf['People'], list(mydf[['Country']], format(mydf$Date, "%Y") ), 
                           FUN=function(d) sum( d >=15 & d <=18) )
    Group.1 Group.2 People
1 Australia    2010     25
2    Canada    2010     22
3    France    2010     24
4 Australia    2011     27
5    Canada    2011     19
6    France    2011     33
7 Australia    2012     19
8    Canada    2012     33
9    France    2012     24
```

If you want the resulting dataframe to have different column names then add those to the list inside the by-group definition:

```
 aggregate( mydf['People'], list(Cntry=mydf[['Country']], Yr=format(mydf$Date, "%Y") ), 
                function(d) sum( d >=15 & d <=18) )
      Cntry   Yr People
1 Australia 2010     25
2    Canada 2010     22
3    France 2010     24
4 Australia 2011     27
5    Canada 2011     19
6    France 2011     33
7 Australia 2012     19
8    Canada 2012     33
9    France 2012     24
```

Comment: And I was coming back to change my `aggregate` call for boolean sum!

Answer (score 2):

For a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[,(People=sum(between(People, 15, 18))), by = .(year(Date), Country)]

   year   Country V1
1: 2010    Canada 22
2: 2010 Australia 17
3: 2010    France 22
4: 2011    Canada 23
5: 2011    France 22
6: 2011 Australia 26
7: 2012    Canada 21
8: 2012    France 29
9: 2012 Australia 26
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider base R aggregation:

```
mydf$Year <- format(mydf$Date, "%Y")
mydf$NumberTime15_18 <- ifelse(mydf$People >= 15 & mydf$People <= 18, 1, 0)

aggregate(NumberTime15_18 ~ Country + Year, mydf, sum)

#     Country Year NumberTime15_18
# 1 Australia 2010              22
# 2    Canada 2010              17
# 3    France 2010              28
# 4 Australia 2011              26
# 5    Canada 2011              24
# 6    France 2011              20
# 7 Australia 2012              16
# 8    Canada 2012              27
# 9    France 2012              21
```